# Implement SWRevealViewController on only one UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I implement SWRevealViewController with UITabbarController via storyboard.
I want to display SWRevealViewController in first UITabBarItem only, in other UITabBarItem i don't want to open SWRevealViewController, that done completely.
But problem is position of UITabBar is not change like viewcontroller while SWRevealViewController is appear.

Please help me.

[image]

**Storyboard structure**
[image]

Comment: You can use UIContainerViewController in your app. More info can be found on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html  and an example http://www.thinkandbuild.it/working-with-custom-container-view-controllers/

Comment: @Gagan_iOS i can't understand how to use. please elaborate.

Comment: ok, You are using UITabBarController & Each tab would have a UIViewController. So you have to add UIContainerView on a particular tab's UIViewController. Here is an example for adding as you want. http://mobileoop.com/how-to-use-container-view-controller   You have to just implement this coding on your tab's UIViewController.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS yes is possible but i think it is very lengthy way. any solution with SWrevealviewcontroller.

Comment: I implemented in this way and now It's upon you. try it if you want.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS wait for SWrevealviewcontroller solution, not found then try your solution.

Comment: SWRevealController needs one Front Controller & one rear view controller. Start your SWRevealController just before the First View Controller in your storyboard. That may help you.

Comment: @BharathVankireddy My initial view controller is tabbarviewcontroller not SWRevealController.

Comment: In my opinion First View Controller means which you added as a controller to your first tab bar item. Make first tab bar item controller as SWRevealController.

Comment: @BharathVankireddy see my storyboard structure.

Comment: what do you want exactly..

Comment: @iOSDeveloper i want change position of tabbar like viewcontoller while reveal is appear.

Comment: check the answer @sudheer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by change position of `UITabbar` manually using `SWRevealViewController` delegate method. 
Put this code in `MenuViewController`.

**`MenuViewController.m`**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController];
    self.tabBar = tbc.tabBar;

    _tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, _tabBar.frame.origin.y, _tabBar.frame.size.width, _tabBar.frame.size.height);
    self.revealViewController.delegate = self;
}

- (void) revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position {
    if (position == FrontViewPositionRight) {
        _tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, _tabBar.frame.origin.y, _tabBar.frame.size.width, _tabBar.frame.size.height);
    }
    else {
        _tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, _tabBar.frame.origin.y, _tabBar.frame.size.width, _tabBar.frame.size.height);
    }
}

- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureMovedToLocation:(CGFloat)location progress:(CGFloat)progress overProgress:(CGFloat)overProgress {
    _tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth * progress, _tabBar.frame.origin.y, _tabBar.frame.size.width, _tabBar.frame.size.height);
}
```